# I can not control my android phone from Windows 10 using anydesk. Input is not allowed

Tags: remote-access, anydesk

I installed anydesk on my android phone has v5 and my PC has Windows 10 and I connect normally but I can not see any buttons for home or back and I can not control the phone using keyboard or mouse.

I made sure to select full access on the mobile (and also the PC) but still I can not control the phone. How I can do that ?